# Aligning two arcs of text in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-path

I'm trying to illustrate how rot13 works, using a figure like the one below.  As you can see, I'm trying to draw two arcs of text, an outer one that shows a list of characters, and an inner one that shows their ASCII character numbers.  My problem is getting the two arcs to line up.  I've fiddled with shifts and font sizes (using fixed-width fonts), but can't get something I'm satisfied with.  Is there a cleaner way to align the text in these two arcs?  Here's the code that generated the example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usepackage{fix-cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[decorate,decoration={text along path,
text={|\fontsize{53pt}{73pt}\selectfont\tt|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz},text align=center}]
(4,0) arc [start angle=265,end angle=-85,radius=4];

\path[decorate,decoration={text along path,
text={|\fontsize{10pt}{30pt}\selectfont\tt|97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122},text align=center}]
(4,6ex) arc [start angle=265,end angle=-85,radius=4cm-6ex];

\draw[-latex,blue]
(4cm,0.8ex) arc [start angle=265,end angle=-85,radius=4cm-0.8ex];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem you're having is that the characters are not equally wide and thus are spaced at different intervals on the arc. I would solve it by using `\hphantom` to force the number spacing to be correct, but that does not seem to compile, or by drawing the letter and character in a single box and then rotating. That will be more complicated however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you could position each character/number manually using polar coordinates.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach [count=\i from 97,evaluate=\i as \Ang using 270-(\i-97)*360/26.5] \letter in {a,...,z}
{
   \node [anchor=base,font=\fontsize{53pt}{60pt}\ttfamily,rotate=\Ang-90] (l\i) at (\Ang:4.5cm) {\letter};
   \node [anchor=base,font=\ttfamily,rotate=\Ang-90] (n\i) at (\Ang:3.6cm) {\i};
}


\draw[-latex,blue] ([yshift=3pt]l97.base) arc [start angle=270,end angle=-75,radius=4.5cm-3pt];

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! That's exactly what I had in mind.  Thanks!